# batch file to backup file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the below script to take the backup of a file when a user logs in. It is saved in a batch file. It creates also a log when the file is copied. Now I want to edit the script so that it also saves the date and time when the file has been copied... Please need ur help Thanks

```
@echo off
REM copy documents
xcopy "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\the folder\the file.xlsm" "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\the folder\Backup\" /c /r /d /y > "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\the folder\Backup\xcopy.log"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works independent of regional date/time format:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%I
REM dt format is now YYYYMMDDhhmmss
echo DateTimeString: %dt%
REM from here you can format Date/Time as you need it:
set dat=%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~2,2%-%dt:~0,4%
echo formatted DateTimeString: %dat%

set tim=%dt:~8,4%
echo Time unformatted without Date: %tim%
set tims=%dt:~8,2%:%dt:~10,2%:%dt:~12,2%
echo Time formatted: %tims%
```

Note: If you want to write the Date/Time to the filename, best choice would be a YYYYMMDDhhmm format, because then the files would sort chronilogical.

`xcopy "source" "destination" > "path\xcopy-%dt%.log"`

To write the date/time into the file, use

`echo %dat%-%tims% >> "path\xcopy.log"`

Comment: Stops working after 2099, though ;-) (or at least works only intermittently then)

Comment: @joey: ok, add another century by replacing '"20"` with `"2"` or even better: `findstr "[0-9]"` ;-)

Comment: Hi Stephan,
how do I display the time?

Comment: thanks Stephan ur solution helps me get the current date and time but it doesn't solve my problem as I need the time and date the fie was copied. My script will only copy the file if it has been modified before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet to get the date and time in a locale-agnostic manner:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime') do if not defined LocalDateTime set LocalDateTime=%%x
set MyDate=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%
set MyTime=%LocalDateTime:~8,6%
```

This is local time, however, so you get the same hour twice at one DST boundary, which is not ideal for log files. I'd advise to use UTC exclusively for those purposes:

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %%x
```

This will set the variables `Day`, `DayofWeek`, `Hour`, `Minute`, `Month`, `Quarter`, `Second`, `WeekInMonth` and `Year` which you can use, then.

Comment: Great answer @Joey! I'm looking to use the UTC time, but I'd like to prepend 0s before single digit numbers. At the moment, the month is spitting out as 9, instead of 09. Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Comment: The usual way is `set Month=0%Month%` and `set Month=%Month:~-2%`

Answer (score 0):

```
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
echo %mydate%_%mytime% >> xcopy.log
```

(`delims` values depends on your regional settings)

Comment: You know, you could just use `%Date%` and `%Time%` instead and it'd still be horrible because all of those depend on the locale.

Comment: @Јοеу, thank you! To avoid dependance on locale we can use [date.exe from UnxTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/): `date.exe +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S >> xcopy.log` (it is correct solution for author of this question, but I am not sure he can use external utils)

Comment: See my answer, which uses only things that are shipped with Windows since Windows 2000. There is no need for using external utilities here. (Personally I try to avoid writing batch files that depend on some system setting because especially here you never know what those settings are and then you'd get a comment that it doesn't work.)

Comment: Llya and Joey,

I am really confused. This is the first time I have used a batch file. So can u pls tell me how I can modify my original script to get the desired output. I am using an office computer so I cannot install any external software. Thanks

Comment: @user3125707, you can just copy&paste any solution in the end of you .bat file. After last `echo` command you have to add `>> "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\the folder\Backup\xcopy.log"` (to append current date and time to your log file)